# Flutter: How Download PDF file saved in google drive

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api, pdf-viewer

I want make Medical Laboratory mobile app using Flutter, I have the accession test api data containt two type of link (ofaccession test) as shown :

```
{
  "viewUrl": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/view?usp=drivesdk",
  "downloadUrl": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=xxxxxxxxxxx",
 }
```

I tried url_launcher and syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer and pdf_render but not work :

```
Future<void> _launchUrl(url) async {
    if (!await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
      throw Exception('Could not launch $url');
    }
}
```